# GoDaddy with redirection of path (DNS)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns, cross-domain, forwarding

I recently booked a domain name with GoDaddy (http://godaddy.com) in order to change the domain of my current website, but it is not working exactly as I want.

To make it simple, I've got a website: `xxx.com/blog` which is working perfectly.
I booked a domain `yyy.com` and I choose the option "Forward With Masking".

So for the homepage, everything is fine. 
When I'm typing `yyy.com` I see the content of `xxx.com/blog` as it should be.

**Problem:** When I'm clicking on a link on the page, (`yyy.com/example`), I see the content of `xxx.com/blog/example`, but the URL stays as `yyy.com`...

I would like to have:

- `xxx.com/blog` --> `yyy.com`
- `xxx.com/blog/example1` --> `yyy.com/example1`
- `xxx.com/blog/example2` --> `yyy.com/example2`
- `xxx.com/blog/2016/08/05/test` --> `yyy.com/2016/08/05/test`

I understand that forward with masking is creating an **Iframe**, so this is not what I want for sure... 
But if I'm putting without masking, then when I'm typing `yyy.com` the URL is changed into `xxx.com/blog` and that's not what I want neither...

I can't change easily the URL on the website unfortunately they have to stay as `xxx.com/blog/example`, (due to some complicated Wordpress configurations)... I just want a way to transform every link `xxx.com/blog` into `yyy.com/` links.

I hope some of you guys will be able to help me :)

Best Regards!

Comment: Until someone more familiar with GoDaddy gives an answer, I strongly suggest that you properly configure this new domain directly on your current web server and skip GoDaddy forwarding service.